# How to define a no-argument constructor in Kotlin file with @Parcelize annotation

Tags: kotlin, constructor, google-cloud-firestore, parcelable, runtimeexception

I am making an app using Firebase Firestore and Authentication. It is logging the user properly but as soon as the user gets authenticated, the app crashes. It gives a runtime exception.

**Could not deserialize object. Class com.swetajain.mapchat.model.User does not define a no-argument constructor.**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.swetajain.mapchat, PID: 4005
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class com.swetajain.mapchat.model.User does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:563)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:54)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:749)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:741)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:542)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:253)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:100)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:187)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:165)
        at com.swetajain.mapchat.ui.LoginActivity$setUpFirebaseAuth$1$1.onComplete(LoginActivity.kt:86)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7136)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

My model class is here: User.kt

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class User(
    var email: String,
    var user_id: String,
    var username: String,
    var avatar: String?
) : Parcelable
```

And my Login class is here: LoginActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreSettings
import com.swetajain.mapchat.MainActivity
import com.swetajain.mapchat.R
import com.swetajain.mapchat.UserClient
import com.swetajain.mapchat.model.User
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*


class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private val TAG = "LoginActivity"
    private val mProgressBar: ProgressBar? = null
    private val mEmail: EditText? = null
    private val mPassword: EditText? = null
    private var mAuthListener: AuthStateListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        setUpFirebaseAuth()

        email_sign_in_button.setOnClickListener(this)
        link_register.setOnClickListener(this)
        hideSoftKeyboard()
    }

    private fun hideSoftKeyboard() {
        this.window
            .setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager
                    .LayoutParams
                    .SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
            )
    }


    private fun setUpFirebaseAuth() {

        Log.d(TAG, "setUpFirebaseAuth: started..")

        mAuthListener = AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
            var firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + firebaseUser.uid)
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@LoginActivity,
                    "Authenticated with: " + firebaseUser.email,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                val settings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                    .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                    .build()
                db.firestoreSettings = settings
                val userRef =
                    db.collection(getString(R.string.collection_users))
                        .document(firebaseUser.uid)
                userRef.get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Log.d(
                                TAG,
                                "onComplete: successfully set the user client."
                            )
                            var user:User =
                                task.result
                                    ?.toObject(
                                        User::class.java
                                    )!!
                            (applicationContext as UserClient).setUser(user = user) 
                        //this line is showing error

                        }
                    }
                val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            } else { // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out")
            }
            // ...
        }


    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.link_register -> {
                startActivity(
                    Intent(
                        this@LoginActivity,
                        RegisterActivity::class.java
                    )
                )
            }
            R.id.email_sign_in_button -> {
                signIn()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun signIn() {

        if (!isEmpty(mEmail!!.text.toString())
            && !isEmpty(mPassword!!.text.toString())
        ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to authenticate.")
            showDialog()
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                mEmail.text.toString(),
                mPassword.text.toString()
            )
                .addOnCompleteListener { hideDialog() }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@LoginActivity,
                        "Authentication Failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    hideDialog()
                }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@LoginActivity,
                "You didn't fill in all the fields.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mAuthListener?.let { FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(it) }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener!!)
        }
    }

    private fun showDialog() {
        mProgressBar?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun hideDialog() {
        when (mProgressBar?.visibility) {
            View.VISIBLE -> mProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```